# Pass String array to Oracle query using jOOQ

Tags: java, oracle, jooq

I'm using the jOOQ code generator to call an query from an Oracle package. One of the parameters of the query is a String array.

The first issue, is that the code generator used `Object` as the type of the parameter. The generated documentation tells me to use an explicit `Binding`, but doesn't say how or where. I assume I have to configure something on the `GenerationTool`. How do I do that?

The second issue, is what actual value to pass. I've tried `String[]` and `List<String>`, but neither work. Then I ended up writing my own simple class:

```
public class MyStringArray extends ArrayRecordImpl<String> {
  public MyStringArray() {
    super(MySchema.MY_SCHEMA, "ARR_STR", SQLDataType.VARCHAR(255));
  }
}
```

This works, but feels like a hack. How do I do it the "nice" way?

Comment: 1) What jOOQ and Oracle versions are you using? 2) What's the definition of your `ARR_STR` type in DDL?

Comment: jOOQ 3.15.4, Oracle 19. I'll check 2) tomorrow when I'm back at work.

Comment: @LukasEder Thanks for the hint! While searching for the ARR_STR type DDL, I found it in another schema, that wasn't being done by the generator. I added it, and a record is generated and it's used by the generated query. So that solves both problems.

Comment: Glad to hear that, I was suspecting that could have been the reason. We should probably improve the generated Javadoc to hint at this being a possible solution, rather than implementing a `Binding` manually: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12630. You can answer your own question here with your findings, to help future visitors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common reason why this happens for user defined types is because the type is in a different schema than the routine referencing it, or it was excluded explicitly using `<excludes>`. In both cases, you can either:

- Do as the hint in the Javadoc suggests, and implement your own binding
- Much better: include the referenced types in your code generation configuration

The generated Javadoc could be improved because jOOQ knows that the type is a user-defined type and that it's missing from generation output. I've created an issue to improve this: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12630